# How do I make this function increment the valor and not overwrite the old one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, dom

```
function calcularSaldo() {
    let valor = ganhos.value - gastos.value
    saldo = 0
    if (saldo > 0) {
        span.id = 'positivo'
        saldo = saldo + valor
    } else if (saldo < 0) {
        span.id = 'negativo'
        saldo = saldo + valor
    } else {
        span.id = 'neutro'
        saldo = valor
    }
    span.innerText = saldo

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        form.reset()
    })
}
```

I want this function to add the new valor to the variable saldo, and show always the newer amount on the screen.
Each conditional will change color based on the amount, if is positive the amount is positive then it will be green, etc.

Comment: Don't do `saldo = 0` in the function. That resets it every time the function is called.